# Silverlight OOB have any limitations?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob, trusted-application

If i check Trusted Aplication on Manifest file, my Silverlight OOB have any limitations??

Ex:  - directory access limitations
     - socket connections limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can read about [Trusted Silverlight Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.96%29.aspx)

The main features are:

- Relaxed Cross-Domain Access
- Restrictions Relaxed User Consent
- Requirements Relaxed User Initiation
- Requirements Full-Screen Support
- Support for Window Customization File
- System Access Native Integration